# Define margins and padding in dimen file in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-view

I am defining the margins or paddings in dimen file

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
 <dimen name="dp_12">12dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and using it in layout as

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_12"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

But it seems it is not reusable becuase in future if I want it to change to 16dp then again I have to define dp_16 in dimen file and change it every single place in layout files wherever I used dp_12. Is it any better way?

Comment: You can use **[SDP - a scalable size unit](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)**

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate using common margin all over the app.

- Make common space dimen like this, by this way you can set them on margin or padding or any spacing property.
- Also if you name `12_dp`, it makes no sense to create it.

Like

```
<dimen name="space_large">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="space_small">8dp</dimen>
```

By this way, you will have same margin or padding in whole app.

Answer (score 0):

create style In Your app and use it on diffrent layout if u want
for example u can use style that have margin 12dp 
and other style have 16 dp 
if u dont want use it

An android SDK that provides a new size unit - sdp (scalable dp). This size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.

its for wiget
https://github.com/intuit/sdp

and for font size :
https://github.com/intuit/ssp